# Networking hardware for OpenStack deployment

Tags: networking, cisco, vlan, openstack

I am looking for some advice on networking equipment for an OpenStack deployment.

I currently have a single ADSL connection coming into a building with a static IP and nothing connected to it currently.

I have two servers - one for a nova controller and one for a compute node.

But what networking equipment should I look into? What I think I need:

- Router for ADSL to give static IP on an Ethernet cable (Does Cisco make these?)
- Switch that's VLAN compatible for different networks in OpenStack

Has anyone done small deployments like this? How have you set it up?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with a single multilayer switch. You will need a switch that can NAT and perform layer 3 switching for faster routing performance.